# Form Building UI for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webforms

I am developing my first Rails app, a web replacement to a paper form system.  Some way through development I discover my client wants to be able to add ad hoc new forms to the live system.

I have considered using wufoo/ google forms/ or survey monkey, but I don't think they are going to fit the bill, due to integration requirements.

What I basically want is to enable one or two super-users to create forms, which will then be available to other users in the system.  When the forms are completed the output should be made available to my system.  The data is to be manually collated for analysis, so even CSV is fine - there is no need for complex modelling.

I have been struggling to find any paths to a solution - I really don't want to build a form builder myself!  So if anybody can point me in the right direction it would be most appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [liquid template](http://www.liquidmarkup.org/) is a good choice for custom building web pages. The easier approach is creating pure HTML pages with form to your system, if your customer allows to.

For the data storage, you'd better try nosql database, such as the [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) and [mongo gem](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver) as the ruby adapter, so you can save any data structure without managing the tables and columns. By the way, you have to learn some ruby meta-programming skills to process the dynamic data from the client.